# Подсказка для участников в чате

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, чат, мета

На текущий момент подсказка, всплывающая при наведении мыши на строку с кол-вом участников в чате

> [image: 60]

имеет разные несогласованные формы (последствия разрозненного перевода):

> [image: разные]

Оригинальная строка выглядит так:

> $users$ users active in $rooms$ rooms the last 60 minutes

Предлагаю выбрать подходящий вариант.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 92 участника активны в 57 чатах (по информации за последний час)

Вариант утвержден на [transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40261791?key=5fcf0f93ca9d717ca31850e9a0b3c0d9). Будет доступен после обновления сайта до версии новее чем 2017.2.28.25254.

Comment: Так ли нужно тут "по информации"?

Comment: @alexolut, в начало ставить не хочется. А в конце вроде надо что-то написать. И "в течение" мне не нравится. Лучше чем "по информации" ничего не придумал.

Comment: Есть ли у Вас возражения, если немного упростить предложение до `92 участника активны в 57 чатах за последний час`?

Comment: @alexolut, мне кажется, что без него что-то не то...

Comment: Без `по информации` или без скобок? Может есть какие-то аналогии для примера?

Comment: @alexolut, "в 57 чатах за последний чат" - что-то не то. надо хотя бы "в течение часа", но тоже звучит странно. Можно было бы "В течение часа в 57 чатах было 92 участника", но это мне нравится меньше из-за второстепенной информации в начале. Поэтому выбрал вариант со скобками. Может, ты сможешь что-то интересное придумать :)

Comment: Я уже придумал два варианта, которые не получили голосов, пора утверждать :) Приму Ваш вариант из ответа, всё-таки это текст хинта, особо гнаться за краткостью тут нет смысла.

Comment: Не всё так [гладко](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35755903#35755903) как хотелось бы.

Comment: Обновления подхватились.

Answer (score 0):

Например, такой (с учётом множественных форм):

> $users$ участников проявили активность в $rooms$ чатах за последний час

Answer (score 0):

> $users$ активных участников в $rooms$ чатах за последний час